# async await with vuex + feathers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuex, feathersjs

Please check below my code. I'm trying to implement Async Await into vuex. Everything is working but I want to call another action after this one so I am trying with async await But it's not working. In console **console.log("after all this" +res)** res variable showing undefined.

**action.js**

```
import { createUpload } from '../api/index'
export default {
    fetchImageUrl: async({ commit }, reader) => {
      let res = await createUpload({ commit }, reader);
      console.log("after all this" +res)
    }
}
```

**api/index.js**

```
import { feathersClient } from './apiClient'
const uploadService = feathersClient.service('uploads');
export const createUpload = ({commit}, reader) => {
  uploadService
    .create({uri: reader.result})
    .then(function(response){
        commit('setImageUrl', { url: response.imageurl })
        return true;
    });
}
```

**mutations.js**

```
export default {
    setImageUrl: (state,{ url } ) => {
      state.imageUrl = url
    }
}
```

**LeftPanel.vue**

```
const reader  = new FileReader();
export default {
  name: 'left-panel',
  data () {
    return {
      open: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadFile: function (event) {
      let store = this.$store;
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        return store.dispatch('fetchImageUrl',reader)
      };
    }
  },
  components: {
    'add-text': AddText
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `return` statement before `uploadService.create`.

index.js

```
export const createUpload = ({commit}, reader) => {
  return uploadService
    .create({uri: reader.result})
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks @alexmac, it's working. Could you please explain it?

Comment: `createUpload` calls `uploadService` function, but so as you don't return a result of this call, it ends immediately.